# "Filtering" huge MariaDB/Mysql table based on different table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Struggling with a large dataset in my mariaDB database. I have two tables, where table A contains 57 million rows and table B contains around 500. Table B is a subset of ids related to a column in table A. I want to delete all rows from A which do not have a corresponding ID in table B.

Example table A:

| classification_id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | Mercedes |
| 30 | Kawasaki |
| 80 | Leitz |
| 70 | HP |

Example table B:

| classification_id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | car |
| 30 | bike |
| 40 | bus |
| 50 | boat |

So in this example the last two rows from table A would be deleted (or a mirror table would be made containing only the first two rows, thats also fine).

I tried to do the second one using an inner join but this query took a few minutes before giving an out of memory exception.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: Clarification needed: does your table B contain 500 rows or 500 _million_ rows?

Comment: Table B contains 500 rows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
delete from "table A" where classification_id not in (select classification_id from "table B");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that the filter table contains a relatively small number of rows, your best bet would be creating a separate table that contains the same columns as the original table `A` and the rows that match your criteria, then replace the original table and drop it. Also, with this number of IDs you probably want to use `WHERE IN ()` instead of joins - as long as the field you're using there is indexed, it will usually be *way* faster. Bringing it all together:

```
CREATE TABLE new_A AS
  SELECT A.* FROM A 
  WHERE classification_id IN (SELECT classification_id FROM B);
RENAME TABLE A TO old_A, new_A to A;
DROP TABLE old_A;
```

Things to be aware of:

- Backup your data! And test the queries thoroughly before running that `DROP TABLE`. You don't want to lose 57M rows of data because of a random answer at StackOverflow.
- If `A` has any indexes or foreign keys, these won't be copied over - so you'll have to recreate them all manually. I'd recommend running `SHOW CREATE TABLE A` first and making note on its structure. Alternatively, you may consider creating the table `new_A` explicitly using the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE A` as a template and then performing `INSERT INTO new_A SELECT ...` instead of `CREATE TABLE new_A AS SELECT ...` with the same query after this.